# $\mathbb{C}$ is *clopen*. What?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I learned in different math courses, that $\mathbb{C}$ is a *clopen* set. I'm very uncertain if I understand this right, please tell me if these two examples are true:

- $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is **open**,
- $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$ is **closed**.

Thanks.

Comment: The examples are true. But they don't show that $\mathbb{C}$ is clopen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A clopen set is a set which is both closed and open.

When talking about a space, it is always clopen in itself. This is because we want both the space and the empty set to be open.

So $\mathbb{C}$ is indeed clopen in $\mathbb{C}$ (in any given topology). However, note that $\mathbb{R}$ is clopen in $\mathbb{R}$, but as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ it's actually just closed. So when you move from $\mathbb{C}$ to something bigger (for example the [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)) then $\mathbb{C}$ is open, and not closed.

Comment: +1 for the hint, that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is closed, but clopen for itself. Thanks.

Comment: And in a connected space the only clopen sets are the empty set and the whole space.

Comment: And when you move from C to C^2, then copies of C are closed, and not open.  The point is that "open" and "closed" are always _relative_ notions and should never be used absolutely.

Comment: To build on Qiaochu's comment, some have suggested that compact (Hausdorff) is the appropriate "absolute" version of closed.  One shouldn't take this too literally, but it can be a helpful heuristic.

Answer (score 9):

The whole space is always clopen in any topology.  That is part of the definition of a topology.  Your two examples are correct.

Comment: The choice of words is a bit unfortunate. Perhaps it is better to use "whole" rather than "complete".

Comment: @Andres:  I agree.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}$ is indeed clopen since it is both open and closed.  Note that one way to define a connected space in topology is that there are no non-trivial clopen sets (the empty set and the whole set will trivially be clopen regardless of the topology).