# Proving $\mathbb{C}$ is clopen.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I want to prove that the set $\mathbb{C}$ is clopen. My initial thought is to show that it is unbounded (but isn't it by definition?). Is it enough? How to properly prove this? Or is this trivial?

Comment: What are your definitions of "closed" and "open"? (There are a number of equivalent ways to define them.)

Comment: In any topological space, the whole space is clopen. So what is your definition of an open set?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  is the closure of C really by definition or as a consequence that C is open? Thank you!

Comment: @R01 One of the axioms of a topological space is that the whole space and the empty set are open. Since a set is closed iff its complement is open, this means that the whole space is closed, since it is the complement of the empty set.

Comment: So that's it. @Prime Mover's approach below is the right one. Since the closure isn't part of the axiom of a topological space but rather there's just a theorem/corollary. Comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17090/mathbbc-is-clopen-what didn't exactly answer my question since they stated it is directly clopen.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, sorry I just want to get things clarified. In the comments here by Tucker: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306519/topological-relation-between-complex-numbers-and-r2#:~:text=A%20topological%20space%20is%20a,topologies%20from%20the%20same%20set. , he said "A topological space is a set and a set of subsets. The set of complex numbers does not refer to a topology, it is a set. "

Comment: @R01 A topological space is an ordered pair $(X, \mathcal T)$ where $X$ is a set and $\mathcal T$ is a subset of the power set of $X$, satisfying the axioms of a topological space. In principle, when you say $\mathbb C$, you have only specified the set $X$ but not $\mathcal T$. On the other hand, more or less any mathematician will implictly take $\mathcal T$ as the topology induced by the metric $d:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C, d(z_1,z_2)=\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert$ if it is not specified.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $\mathbb C$ as a topological space, both $\mathbb C$ and $\varnothing$ are open in $\mathbb C$.

But then by definition of closed set, both $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb C = \varnothing$ and $\mathbb C \setminus \varnothing = \mathbb C$ are also closed in $\mathbb C$.

So $\mathbb C$ and $\varnothing$ are "at the same time closed and open" in $\mathbb C$.

Hence both are "clopen" by definition of "clopen".

Comment: some comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17090/mathbbc-is-clopen-what say that $\mathbb{C}$ is clopen by definition of $\mathbb{C}$ as a topological space. I find your proof nice since it first takes the "open-ness" of $\mathbb{C}$ before its closure.

Comment: @R01 Thank you for your vote of confidence. I specifically added this answer because a) the question of which this was supposed to be a duplicate isn't the same as this and b) none of the answers of that question were any good.

Comment: But, is the closure of $\mathbb{C}$ really by definition or as a consequence that $\mathbb{C}$ is open? Thank you!

Comment: The definition (or at least *one* definition) of "closed set (of a topological space)" is "the complement of an open set (relative to that topological space)". So it's definitional.

Comment: I mean, is it by definition of topology? Btw, yeah, I know that definition of complement.

Comment: But from that response, I see that it is a consequence rather than a definition of topology. Thanks!

Comment: sorry I just want to get things clarified. In the comments here by Tucker: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306519/topological-relation-between-complex-numbers-and-r2#:~:text=A%20topological%20space%20is%20a,topologies%20from%20the%20same%20set. , he said "A topological space is a set and a set of subsets. The set of complex numbers does not refer to a topology, it is a set. "

Comment: The set of complex numbers endowed with the standard Euclidean metric, that is, the modulus function, is a metric space, which induces a topology whose basis consists of the open discs in $\mathbb C$. Or something like that. So while Tucker is technically correct, there is a case for considering $\mathbb C$ as a topological space, and in doing so, the open sets can then be defined in the topological way. Apologies if this is above your pay grade.

Comment: Aight! I'll try to understand this. Thank you so much!